# Detect if the user is a new customer or an old one in shopify additional scripts

Tags: shopify, liquid, checkout, affiliate

I am developing an affiliate pixel script to put in the additional scripts sections of a Shopify shop.

I should calculate the commission to be given to the affiliate based on the state of the customer. I will give the affiliate different commission if the customer is new or old.

Is that a way to detect if the customer is a new or an old one in the additional scripts sections of Shopify even if the customer is not signed in?

Comment: If he's not signed in, what kind of information do you have?

Comment: Hello Fabio, thank you for your reply. The user should fill the checkout's information even if his not signed in. So he will put his email. I am wondering if there is a Shopify predefined object on the tank you page that can give me the information if the email filled matchs with a customer account or not. I tried {checkout.customer} and {order.customer} but the in the two cases the customer object is null if the user is not signed in.

Comment: If it's not logged in Shopify doesn't retrieve the information. My best shot would be having a app that given the email return the info.